# How to show all data in USERS Model in my profile page

Tags: django

`views.py`
Here i have made logic where i have passed user data in my profile file but still it shows not output there

```
#Authenciation APIs
def handleSignup(request):
    
     if request.method=='POST':
          #Get the post parameters
          username=request.POST['username']
          fname=request.POST['fname']
          lname=request.POST['lname']
          email=request.POST['email']
          pass1=request.POST['pass1']
          pass2=request.POST['pass2']

          #checks for errorneous input
          #username should be <10
          # username shouldbe alphanumeric

          if len(username)>10:
                messages.error(request,"username must be less than 10 characters")
                return redirect('/')
          if not username.isalnum():
                messages.error(request,"username should only contain letters and numbers")
                return redirect('/')
          if pass1!=pass2:
               messages.error(request,"Password do not match")
               return redirect('/')

          #Create the user
          myuser=User.objects.create_user(username,email,pass1)
          myuser.first_name=fname
          myuser.last_name=lname
          myuser.save()

          messages.success(request,"your Musify account has been created succesfully Now go enter your credentials into the login form")
          return redirect('/')

     else:
          return HttpResponse('404 - Not Found')

def handleLogin(request):
     if request.method=='POST':

          #Get the post parameters
          loginusername=request.POST['loginusername']
          loginpassword=request.POST['loginpassword']

          user=authenticate(username=loginusername,password=loginpassword)

          if user is not None:
               login(request,user)
               messages.success(request,"succesfully Logged In")
               return redirect('/')              
          else:
               messages.error(request,"Invalid credentials Please try again")
               return redirect('/')
               
               
     return HttpResponse('404 - Not Found')


def profile(request):
    user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    d={'user':user}
    return render(request,'profile.html',d)
```

`profile.html`
I have made sign up form where i have username,firstname,lastname,email fields in it.
and i want to display this field on my profile page But its not working,not showing any output on my profile page.

```
profile here

{% for i in d %}
{{i.email}}
{{i.firstname}}
{{i.lastname}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not `d` you need to refer to, it's the dict key `user` ...

Comment: did it but it says its not iterable

Comment: It's not, it's a single `User` object. You can't use it in a `for` loop

Comment: can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: Get rid of the `for` loop in the template, and just refer to the fields as `user.email` etc.

Comment: with is i got username and email but didnt got first and last name!

Comment: I've added an answer to clarify

Comment: yes did same thing for all
        {{user.email}}
        {{user.firstname}}
          {{user.lastname}} 
           {{user.username}} but didnt get output in first and lastname

Comment: Have you done as my answer below? If so, then you have no data in firstname & lastname. Have you checked these fields match what you have defined on the model? A template will not throw an error if you reference a field that doens't exist, it will just show nothing.

Comment: yes i have checked this fields are present in my user model but dont know why still it shows no output

Comment: See extended answer below re. field names on `User` model ...

Comment: yes,everything is proper i have checked but still not working

Comment: myuser=User.objects.create_user(username,email,pass1,fname,lname) i changed this line in views and i got the output

Answer (score 0):

you tape for i in d , but the model created is named myuser, so you should put it as the limite of your loop, so try this on your HTML file :

```
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>firstname</th>
                    <th>lastname</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in myuser %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.firstname}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

I create a table to display them clearly.

Comment: still i am not getting user name,email,firstname

Answer (score 0):

This code is returning a single `User` object, using the `get` method:

```
def profile(request):
    user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    d={'user':user}
    return render(request,'profile.html',d)
```

The data passed to the template is the data contained within `d`, but `d` cannot be referenced in the template itself. It's only in  your view.

So - one object. No need for a loop. You can simply do:

```
profile here

{{ user.email }}
{{ user.firstname }}
{{ user.lastname }}
```

You refer to is using `user` because this is the dictionary key you have given it in the context data (`d`) that you passed to the template.

Note that this has no formatting, line breaks or anything though. To make it clear, use a table, or just put some labels and breaks in or you're just going to get all your data on one line, which may be confusing ... :

```
<h1>profile here</h1>
Email: {{ user.email }}
<br>
First name: {{ user.firstname }}    
<br>
Last name: {{ user.lastname }}
```

One more comment. Standard Django `User` model uses the field names `first_name` and `last_name`, so if you haven't changed the model, and are trying to use that, make sure you reference the correct field names!

Comment: first name and last name are not displaying email and username are displaying

Comment: ok,thanks i did  one change in code and i got the answer

Comment: myuser=User.objects.create_user(username,email,pass1,fname,lname)

Comment: i did this change and i got the answer